# Bootstrap typeahead displays only first letter of the array

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I type letter 'a'

The output comes as follows

```
    A
    A
    A
    A
    A
```

If I type 'ad'
it disappears

expected output
when typing 'a'

```
*Adilabad
*Adoni
*Amadalavalasa
*Amalapuram
```

php code for fetching db table data

```
<?php include_once 'db.php';
     $sql = 'SELECT city_name FROM master_city';
     $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

my html code

```
 <input class="input-xlarge focused" 
        id="emp_peraddress_city" name="emp_peraddress_city" 
        type="text" placeholder="city" 
        data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" 
        data-source="<?php 
    echo"["; 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ 
        echo "'".$row["city_name"]."',"; 
    } 
    echo"]"; ?>">
```

The echo sample of my data returned from database is :

```
['Kolhapur','Port Blair','Adilabad','Adoni','Amadalavalasa','Amalapuram','Anakapalle','Anantapur','Badepalle','Banganapalle','Bapatla','Bellampalle','Bethamcherla','Bhadrachalam','Bhainsa','Bheemunipatnam','Bhimavaram','Bhongir','Bobbili','Bodhan','Chilakaluripet','Chirala','Chittoor','Cuddapah','Devarakonda']
```

Comment: As far as I can tell your test data has no "ab" names in  it. Does the same problem occur if you type 'ad' or 'am'?

Comment: There's nothing having a start with `ab` names.

Comment: No It contains 1500 city names .. I have just given sample of it.Even if i give 'ad' also it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your city names should be in double quote, like this `data-source='["city-1","city-2","city-3"]'`.

The data-source should be in JSON format while your output is taken as a string that's why you are getting only the first letter.

Comment: Yes, Could you say how do i convert string to json, I have tried like this  $convert = json_decode($data);

Comment: use process(JSON.parse(yourdata)); instead of process(yourdata); Didn't my above solution work for you?

Comment: No, How can I convert string array to json..??

Comment: say we put your data output in $yourdata, then JSON.parse(yourdata) will parse your string to JSON.

Comment: Yes thankyou , your answer worked for me .. I have used this to work...$convert_city = json_encode($data_city);.. Problem is my array contains some 1500 city name.. my array - $data_city in php is restricting based on default memory given for arrays in php... I am working on it to increase the memory... could you help me out...

Comment: If you do want to modify the memory limit, check php.ini and look for memory_limit = 128M(the number may vary). Depending on your server configuration you can increase to 256 or 512 or even more. But this is not the best solution. I have a project using 200K+ data entries and we have no such problem. You should prepare your query in a more logical way.

Comment: Thanks boss!!! Your answers was really helpful.. Thanks for your help.. I solved by removing all php's regarding auto suggest and done with jquery which solved the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your contribution for getting the result...
This is the code I have done with to get auto-suggest.

I have removed my php codes and done using jquery

HTML part

```
 <input class='input-xlarge focused' id='emp_peraddress_city' name='emp_peraddress_city' type='text' data-provide='typeahead' data-items='4' data-source='cities'></br>
```

The jquery part

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'add_employee/fetch_city_names.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            var cities = response;

            $('#emp_peraddress_city').typeahead({source: JSON.parse(cities)});

        }

    });
```

PHP part: fetch_city_names.php

```
<?php 
  include_once '../db.php';
 // auto suggest for city
 $sql_city = 'SELECT city_name FROM master_city ORDER BY city_name';

  $res_city = mysqli_query($con, $sql_city);
   $data_city = array();
  while ($row_city = mysqli_fetch_array($res_city)) {

  $data_city[].=$row_city["city_name"];
    }
  $convert_city = json_encode($data_city); // converting String array to JSON

    echo $convert_city;
    mysqli_close($con);             

    ?>
```

Thanks everybody..